# WebBrowser and BackgroundWorker VB

Tags: vb.net

Can a `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event executes the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` correctly? Because my program doesn't seem to execute the codes under BackgroundWorker.

Code:

```
Dim Status As String = ""
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If Status = "Enabled" Or Status = "Disabled" Then
    Else
        Status = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(Account & "Flag").InnerText.ToString
        If Status = "Enabled" Then
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        ElseIf Status = "Disabled" Then
            MessageBox.Show("disabled. Contact admin for more information.", "JKLorenzo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: _Have you tried_ making some sort of indicator telling if the `RunWorkerAsync()` is run or not? All in all, start learning how to use [**the debugger**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx).

Comment: @VisualVincent i have solved it. I almost recoded the app so that i can get rid of checkforillegalcrossthreadedcalls that is set to false before. That was my problem, so I try to fix the errors one by one and hooray! I did it! Thanks though!

Comment: Glad to hear :)! Though you should've never set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to False in the first place... For future reference you can check my example about thread-safety on the [**Stack Overflow documentation**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1913/threading/6235/performing-thread-safe-calls-using-control-invoke#t=201609071725015139138).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it to work

Here is the code i've used:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10)
    Dim mysqlconnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=85.10.205.173;port=3306;username='" & User & "';password='" & Pass & "'")
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(20)
    Dim mysqlcommand As MySqlCommand = Nothing
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(30)
    Dim mysqldatareader As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(40)
    mysqlconnection.Open()
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50)
    Using table As DataTable = New DataTable
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(60)
        Using command As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from my.accounts where Username = 'Ray';", mysqlconnection)
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(70)
            Using adapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(80)
                adapter.Fill(table)
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(90)
            End Using
        End Using

        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            If row("Flag") = "enable" Then
                e.Result = "1"
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100)
            Else
                e.Result = "0"
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100)
            End If
        Next
    End Using
    mysqlconnection.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    If e.ProgressPercentage = 10 Then
        Label1.Text = "Status: Checking"
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight)
    End If
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    ProgressBar1.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    If e.Result = "1" Then
        Label1.Text = "Status: Enabled"
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = True
    ElseIf e.Result = "0" Then
        Label1.Text = "Status: Disabled"
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.OrangeRed
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = False
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Unknown output: " & e.Result & " . Closing", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```